# Este es mi Código de php Pero al momento de buscar no encuentra Caracteres Especiales ñ á entre otras cosas

Tags: php

```
<?php
      header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
      include ("conexion.php");
      $codigo=$_POST['codigo'];
      mysql_select_db($db,$conexion) or die ("ERROR AL 
            CONECTARSE AL SERVIDOR");
      $registros=mysql_query("SELECT *FROM REGISTRO WHERE  nombre_com='$codigo'");

      while($registro=mysql_fetch_array($registros)){
            echo "<h3>";
                echo "<th>";
                    echo "<strong>"; 
                        echo "Nombre Completo";
                    echo "</strong>"; 
                echo "</th>";
            echo "</h3>";                             
      };
?>
```

Comment: Para no tener problema con los acentos, también hay que poner un charset adecuado a la conexión misma, por ejemplo haciendo esto antes de la consulta: `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conexion);` Si sigue dando problemas tendrás que revisar los datos mismos en la base de datos, a ver si no están declarados con una codificación dificultosa o guardados desde fuentes con codificación problemática. Otra cosa, la API `mysql_` está obsoleta, convendría que cambies a mysqli o a PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, lo primero es que en su código asumiendo que la conexión está bien implementada en el documento "conexion.php", está haciendo uso de una función que ya estas alturas está obsoleta (mysql_select_db y mysql_query). Pero el principal problema en lo que nos plantea, es que en el bucle while, solo imprime las etiquetas y el texto que aparece ahí, pero en ningun caso accede a la variable $registro. Para que se entienda, debería ser algo como:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    $codigo=$_POST['codigo'];

    $conexion = new mysqli("host", "usuario", "contraseña", "base_de_datos");

    $registros=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM REGISTRO WHERE nombre_com='$codigo'");

    while($registro=$registros->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<h3>";
            echo "<th>";
                echo "<strong>"; 
                    echo "Nombre Completo ".$registro['nombre_com'];
                echo "</strong>"; 
            echo "</th>";
        echo "</h3>";                             
    };
?>
```

Ahora, con respecto a poder encontrar caracteres especiales, en el dato almacenado en $_POST['codigo'], debe asegurarse de procesar el texto con funciones como "utf8_encode" y muchas otras que dependerá de tu necesidad cuál vas a utilizar.